# CertFindCertificateInStore fails with Oject or property not found

Tags: cryptoapi, certificate-store

Actually i am searching certificate on the basis of common name. For that we have done :-

```
PSTR pszCommonName = "cn.com"; 
CERT_RDN_ATTR certRDNAttr[1]; 
certRDNAttr[0].pszObjId = szOID_COMMON_NAME; 
certRDNAttr[0].dwValueType = CERT_RDN_PRINTABLE_STRING; 
certRDNAttr[0].Value.pbData = (PBYTE) pszCommonName; 
certRDNAttr[0].Value.cbData = lstrlen(pszCommonName); 
CERT_RDN certRDN = {1, certRDNAttr};
```

`// Find the certificate context 
    if (pCertContext =  CertFindCertificateInStore(hCertStore, X509_ASN_ENCODING                                      | PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING, 0, CERT_FIND_SUBJECT_ATTR, &certRDN, NULL))`

My Store contains the desired Cert with given common name but it is not located by the api, it returns null.

Not able to find the issue.